# Unexplainable code behavior with Unit test

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, nunit

I have the following object (simplified port from Delphi) under a NUnit test using VS 2012.

```
Public Class Class1
  Private fLoaded As Boolean
  Private fSample As String

  Private Sub LoadFromDB()
    If (fLoaded) Then
      Exit Sub
    End If

    fLoaded = True
    ' fDataModule.LoadFromDB(Me)
  End Sub

  Public Property SampleProp() As String
    Get
  LoadFromDB()
      Return fSample
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      fSample = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Property Loaded() As Boolean
    Get
      Return fLoaded
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
      fLoaded = value
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

The object is suppose to perform a Load-on-Demand when it's properties are accessed. The following Nunit class is testing the property.

```
Imports NUnit.Framework

<TestFixture> _
Public Class TestClass1

  <Test()> _
  Public Sub TestProperties()
    Dim TheClass As Class1

    TheClass = New Class1
    TheClass.Loaded = True

    TheClass.SampleProp = "Sample"
    TheClass.Loaded = False

    Assert.AreEqual("Sample", TheClass.SampleProp)

  End Sub

End Class
```

The problem that occurs is that with a breakpoint on the Assert Statement, the class property Loaded shows as True in the debugger, without any of my code having been executed that would set the internal variable. The end result is that my on-demand load will not get executed.

What is changing the value of the property? In Delphi, using DUnit, the class properties behaved as expected.

Comment: Could it be because in order to check the value of `SampleProp` the assertion has to call for its value, which in turn runs `LoadFromDB()`, which sets `Loaded` to `True`?  Why are you manually setting `Loaded` to `True` in the unit test?

Comment: The big problem is that the Assert has not yet executed! I am stopping in the debugger at the Assert line, and the Loaded property reads True. When the Assert actually queries the property, the load-on-demand is bypassed because of the flag state. My big question is who is changing the state of my internal, private class variable?

Comment: Your private variable is not all that private since you can (and are) changing it externally.  I have to say that I thought I saw what you are talking about the first time I ran it - but ONLY the first time as I was starting to make the changes below.  Looked strange but I could not reproduce it after the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Adrian is correct on this, the Assert line is triggering the flag to set.  This issue looked interesting, so I copied it to see what it is doing.  I made a few small changes:

```
Public Class Class1
    Private fLoaded As Boolean = False      ' vars in MY code are never nothing
    Private fSample As String = ""          '    without my say so

  ...

Private Sub LoadFromDB()
  If (fLoaded) Then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  fLoaded = True
  Debug.Print("Now, all your datas are belong to me.")
End Sub
```

And in Test class:

```
Public Sub TestProperties()
  Dim TheClass As New Class1

    TheClass.Loaded = True
    TheClass.SampleProp = "Sample"
    TheClass.Loaded = False
    TheClass.SampleProp = "Not Sample"


    Debug.Assert(("Sample" = TheClass.SampleProp), "Msg")
End Sub
```

Most of the changes are meaningless.  The print line in `LoadFromDB()` is meant to determine WHEN from WHERE the load is firing.  The Assert **IS** causing the DataLoad.  In Debug it LOOKS spontaneous and freaky to be on the Assert line and jump to to Load procedure but that is how you have it written.

Since GETTING not SETTING a prop triggers the load, `TheClass.SampleProp = "Sample"` does nothing as far as the Loaded flag is concerned.  So just before the Assert I added:

```
    If TheClass.SampleProp = "Not Sample" Then
        Debug.Print("Test did that")
    End If
```

The data does load as a result of the Property Get, AND the Assert no longer does because my new line also sets the loaded flag to true.  It is all seems to be working as it should based on how it is written.

EDIT:
I reverted the variable declarations and added a Sub New:

```
    Private fLoaded As Boolean 
    Private fSample As String 

Public Sub New()
    Debug.Print("New == {0}", fLoaded)
End Sub
```

`New` Always reports the member var as `False`.  However in Debug, the mouseover does show the Property value as `True`.

Oddly, by time you get to the Assert, `Loaded` has been set and reset so by then you might expect it to be accurate. If you trace into the Property Get statement in the Assert, you'll see that `fLoaded` is initially false.  The same thing happens right after

```
    Dim TheClass As New Class1
```

The mouse pop up displays True even though New just reported False.

Since both errors are resolved by initializing `fLoaded` it looks to be an error in the mouseover value display of `Loaded` when dealing with uninitialized vars.

The lesson is, initialize variables whenever possible.

Comment: You are correct about the GET before the SET triggering the fLoaded flag to toggle and I was familiar with that. However, the thing that confuses me is that when setting a breakpoint on the Assert test line, my object code get's executed outside my control. Setting a breakpoint on the Assert line, the Debug print statement shows that my internal code has already executed at the time the debugger stops. Even breakpoints in my object code are not observed at that time. I verified that my code is working correctly, so I just have to live with and remember this strange behavior.

Comment: See the edit I made - I could see no 'unwanted code execution' - the Assert statement WILL set `floaded` and it is supposed to.  It LOOKS like breakpoints are being ignored when the mouseover reports True when you know it to be False.  That does not mean code must be executing outside your control - in this case it mean the mouseover report is wrong.  More importantly, when the variables are initialized, everything works the same and the debug value displays are accurate.  (I dont know which `Debug print statement shows...` you mean - my version is littered with them now.

Answer (score 0):

I had cases where object-preview of the debugger was triggering the getter and therefore the preload of my object.