# String Value not empty but cannot do anything with it? VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi this is really baffling me and im sure it simple but i cant work out why its happening.

I am reading a text file and finding a startpos and endpos to extract data. The data i am extracting is - "version is 10.2.0.5.0"

I have the value as i can msgbox it out. And when dubugging if i hover the mouse over the OraContents string it shows me "version is 10.2.0.5.0" which is correct.

So there are a few msgboxes to test things which will be removed...

The problem is when i try and like in this example Write the OraContents to file as in main code snippet.. its says Null and errors even though i have a value assigned to OraContents - or i have tried simply saying the following...

```
If OraContents = "version is 10.2.0.5.0" Then
MsgBox("Oracle found")
End If
```

and again it ignores the If statement it just skips past it because OraContents is not matching the value but it is!

What am i missing... : \

Thanks in advance.

My Code..

```
Sub GetFiles()

    Dim DirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(ProgramFiles & "Oracle\Inventory\logs")
    For Each file As FileSystemInfo In DirInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()

 Dim myFile = IO.Directory.GetFiles(ProgramFiles & "Oracle\Inventory\logs").OrderByDescending(Function(f) New FileInfo(f).LastWriteTime).First()

        If InStr(file.FullName, "installActions") Then

 MsgBox(myFile)
            Dim testTxt As New StreamReader(myFile)
            Dim allRead As String = testTxt.ReadToEnd()
            testTxt.Close()

 If InStr(allRead, "Oracle Universal Installer") Then

                Dim OraContents As String
                OraContents = allRead

                Dim StartPos, EndPos As Integer
                StartPos = OraContents.IndexOf("INFO: Oracle Universal Installer version is ")
                EndPos = OraContents.IndexOf("INFO: Oracle Universal Installer version is ")
                StartPos = StartPos + 32
                EndPos = EndPos + 55

 OraContents = OraContents.Substring(StartPos, EndPos - StartPos)

MsgBox(OraContents)

                Test(OraContents) 'This is a check to make sure value is not Null..its not

System.IO.File.Create("c:\OracleVersion.txt")
                Dim path As String = "c:\OracleVersion.txt"
                Dim sw As StreamWriter

sw.WriteLine(OraContents)

                sw.Close()

End If

MsgBox("Found")
        Else
            'MsgBox("Not Found")
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You may have a character in your string that isn't displaying (maybe a \0 at the start?). Check its length, and see if it tallies with the length of the string you're comparing it to.

Comment: Try changing `Dim OraContents As String` to `Dim OraContents As String = ""`.  The mouseover display can be wrong with uninitialized variables.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902042/unexplainable-code-behavior-with-unit-test/18906566?noredirect=1#comment27928377_18906566

Comment: use tolower() and trim() for both strings that might remove unwanted chars.

Comment: Hi thanks - when i msgbox the string out is shows this...  version is 10.2.0.5.0 so it looks ok..

Comment: thanks xpda i got this back when checking the contents...  32 118 101 114 115 105 111 110 32 105 115 32 49 48 46 50 46 48 46 53 46 48 13

Comment: but this is based on OraContents which was this......                                                     OraContents = OraContents.Substring(StartPos, EndPos - StartPos)

Comment: @Plutonix i tried that and no joy.. still errored when trying to write OraContents to file

Comment: @xpda this is the result i got, what would that indicate this ? 32 118 101 114 115 105 111 110 32 105 115 32 49 48 46 50 46 48 46 53 46 48 13

Comment: Using the Text visualizer my String =version is 10.2.0.5.0 - i just cannot do anything with it.. so surely invalid characters would show with the text visualizer? or not?

Comment: @Plutonix I took the space out and i still get the same problem - also i tried the DebugViewString(OraContents) and it cant do anything with it - it treats it like the other things im trying to do - just skips past it.

Comment: i am invoking it after 'OraContents = OraContents.Substring(StartPos, EndPos - StartPos)' using this..  DebugViewString(OraContents) - is that right?

Comment: thats right...the sub wont DO anything though like pop up msgbox, it provides a point for you to set a break point to view the character contents...even if EMpty, it should not 'skip over it' unless some other exception is being encountered...have you tried Option Strict?

Comment: @Plutonix  Sorry was at lunch - option strict is on...

Comment: @the_lotus It was the carriage return. All your answers pertained to some help and i thank you all. Definitely helped me but i can only give the correct answer to one it wont let me choose multiple. Thanks!

Comment: The variable sw is null so when you call WriteLine on it, it throws the exception.  `Dim sw As New StreamWriter(path)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your string content (32 118 101 114 115 105 111 110 32 105 115 32 49 48 46 50 46 48 46 53 46 48 13), the last character "13" is a new line which cannot really be seen when printing it. Try to trimg your string before comapring.

```
If OraContents.Trim() = "version is 10.2.0.5.0" Then
```

Or get one last character

```
OraContents = OraContents.Substring(StartPos, EndPos - StartPos - 1)
```

You can always see the difference by printing the length

```
MessageBox.show(OraContents.Length & ":" & "version is 10.2.0.5.0".Length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the contents of the string to see if there are any hidden or unexpected characters. You can do the same for the constant if you need to.

```
dim s as string
For i As Integer = 0 To Len(OraContents) - 1
  s = s & Asc(OraContents.Chars(i)) & " "
Next i
msgbox(s) ' or debug / watch
```

You can use `OraContents = OraContents.trim` to get rid of spaces, carriage returns (the 13 in your case), line feeds, etc. on both ends of the string.

Incidentally, if the string is being entered by the user, you might want to do a comparison that ignores upper/lower case differences:

```
if string.compare(OraContents.trim, "Oracle Universal Installer", true) = 0 then
```